# Increase Font Size of HTML parsed string - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

`dummyString` is my HTML content stored as string. Then I am using,

```
 dummyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span style=\"font-family: HelveticaNeue-Thin; font-size: 18\">%@</span>", dummyString];
```

to set the Attributes (18 is my default font size).

Then I am using following line of code to parse HTML content to be presented in UIScrollView.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *dummy = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                 initWithData: [dummyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                 options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
                                 documentAttributes: nil
                                 error: nil
                                 ];
```

If I change the font-size from default(18) to some other size (say 36), size of the text does not increase instead the spacing of the letters increases. Adding the screenshots:

[image: font-size == 18]

[image: font-size == 36]

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: dummyString = [dummyString stringByAppendingString:@"<style>strong{font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Thin ';font-size: 36px;}</style>"];

Comment: where are you loading html string in web view or text view

Comment: Loading in TextView

Answer (score 0):

I've written this in swift. I'm removing the old font and tgen adding my own in the whole range.

```
let   dummyString = NSString(format:"<span style=\"font-family: HelveticaNeue-Thin; font-size: 9\">hi this string</span>")

    do{
        let attributedString = try NSMutableAttributedString.init(data:dummyString.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue)!, options:[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes:nil)

        attributedString.beginEditing()
        attributedString.enumerateAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, in:NSMakeRange(0,attributedString.length), options: NSAttributedString.EnumerationOptions(rawValue: 0), using: { (vaue, range, stop) in
            attributedString .removeAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, range:range)
            // you can use any font
            let newFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize:25)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: newFont, range:range)
        })
        attributedString.endEditing()
    textView.attributedText = attributedString
    }catch{
    }
}
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation UILabel (HTML)

- (void)jaq_setHTMLFromString:(NSString *)string {

string = [string stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"  <style>body{font-family: '%@'; font-size:%fpx;}</style>",
                                          self.font.fontName,
                                          self.font.pointSize]];
self.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                                       options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                                 NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                                            documentAttributes:nil
                                                         error:nil];
}
```

Comment: Same result! No change